# Fastest way to reduce number of latitude and longitude points

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

I'm trying to reduce and combine a number of points to the center point of those locations.  Right now I'm brute-forcing it by finding the closest pair, combining those and repeating until I've reduced it to my target (side note: actually I reduced the problem by sorting by `(lat*lat+long*long)` then searching 10% on either side of each point, which with my tests has always found the shortest distance within that range).

For an example I'd want to reduce 4000 points down to 1000, ideally combining the closest points into the center of those closest points.  Basically to build marker points that reflect the number of addresses in that area.

Is there any better algorithm that would give me as accurate as possible results?  Or a quicker distance algorithm?  I guess it does only need to be accurate at short distances

---

Right now I'm finding the distance with (Wikipedia had it under "spherical earth projected to a plane"):

```
double dLat = pos2.LatitudeR - pos1.LatitudeR;
double dLon = pos2.LongitudeR - pos1.LongitudeR;

double cosLatM = Math.Cos((pos2.LatitudeR + pos1.LatitudeR)/2) * dLon;
double a = dLat*dLat + cosLatM*cosLatM;
```

I've thought about grouping all the points within x distance of each other, then expanding x until I get to my target number of final points, but I'm not sure how to make that as accurate as my perfectionism would want it.  That is all the ways I can think of would vary slightly depending on the order of the input list of points.

---

Edit to describe how my current algorithm processes (This is the ideal way to find the results I want, but an approximation that is much quicker would be worth it):

Describing it linearly, if you had `x=1,4,5,6,10,20,22`

1. It would combine 4+5=4.5 [first 1.0 distance it finds]
2. (4.5*2+6)/3=5 -- `x=1,5,10,20,22` [1.5 distance]
3. 20+22=21 -- `x=1,5,10,21` [2.0 distance]
4. (5*3+1)/4=4 -- `x=4,10,21` [4.0 distance]
5. (4*4+10)/5.2 -- So you'd end up with `x=5.2,21`.  (It keeps track of the CombineCount so it can find the correct average center in this way)

---

**Results:**
Here is my current Distance function, with lookup table generation for cos^2.  Haven't had time to check how close together my points are, so haven't implemented Joey's suggestion of approximating the cos^2, but that could improve the speed over the lookup table here.

The K-Cluster algorithm I tried (see my comment on that answer) did not combine them as I wanted, it ended up with a ton of points near the center of the map and few points toward the edges.  So unless I can correct that I'm using my algorithm which is slower.

```
public static double Distance(AddressCoords pos1, AddressCoords pos2, DistanceType type)
{
    if (LookupTable == null) LookupTable = BuildLookup();

    double R = (type == DistanceType.Miles) ? 3960 : 6371;

    double dLat = pos2.LatitudeR - pos1.LatitudeR;
    double dLon = pos2.LongitudeR - pos1.LongitudeR;

    double LatM = ((pos2.LatitudeR + pos1.LatitudeR)/2);
    if (LatM < 0) LatM = -LatM; //Don't allow any negative radian values
    double cosLatM2 = LookupTable[(int)(LatM * _cacheStepInverse)];
    double a = dLat*dLat + cosLatM2 * dLon*dLon;

    //a = Math.Sqrt(a);

    double d = a * R;

    return d;
}

private const double _cacheStep = 0.00002;
private const double _cacheStepInverse = 50000;

private static double[] LookupTable = null;

public static double[] BuildLookup()
{
    // set up array
    double maxRadian = Math.PI*2;
    int elements = (int)(maxRadian * _cacheStepInverse) + 1;

    double[] _arrayedCos2 = new double[elements];
    int i = 0;
    for (double angleRadians = 0; angleRadians <= maxRadian;
        angleRadians += _cacheStep)
    {
        double cos = Math.Cos(angleRadians);
        _arrayedCos2[i] = cos*cos;
        i++;
    }
    return _arrayedCos2;
}
```

Comment: Just to understand your requirements a bit better, what would happen if your 4000 points were completely uniformly distributed across the grid?

Comment: If that were the case, my requirements wouldn't care which pairs it chooses to combine... If they were all squares, I think my current algorithm would combine the first two next to each other it finds into a center point. Halfway through it would have rectangles, then combine those closest pairs to get the center point of 4 points.  If it was not reduced by a power of 2, it would depend on the order of the points

Comment: What would you want to happen if you had 3 points close together with the others a long way away? Combine two and leave the other alone? Combine two and then combine the other with one a long way away? Something else?

Comment: Yes, I think you understood it, but to make sure I added an example of each iteration of my current code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To speed up working out distances between points:

If you do some elementary algebra you get:

```
D = R*Sqrt(Lat2^2 + Lat1^2 - 2*Lat1*Lat2 + cos^2((Lat2 + Lat1) /2)(Lon2^2 + Lon1^2 - 2*Lon1*Lon2))
```

The first thing you can do to speed this up is normalise to the radius of the Earth (R) and compare squared distances rather than distances, thus avoiding the square root and R term, saving yourself 2 calculations per comparison. Leaving:

```
valToCompare = Lat2^2 + Lat1^2 - 2*Lat1*Lat2 + cos^2((Lat2 + Lat1) /2)(Lon2^2 + Lon1^2 - 2*Lon1*Lon2)
```

Another thing you could do is precalculate Lat^2 and Lon^2 for each coordinate - reducing the number of calculations for each comparison by 4.

Further, if the points are all relatively close together in latitude you could take an approximation for the cos^2 term by precalculating it using the latitude of a random point or the average latitude of all the points, rather than the average latitude of the two points being compared. This reduces the number of calculations for each comparison by another 4.

Finally, you could pre-calculate 2*Lat and 2*Lon for each point cutting out 2 more calculations for each comparison.

None of this improves your algorithm per se but it should make it run faster and can be applied to any algorithm that needs to compare the distances between points.

Comment: Don't forget latitude and longitude must be in radians for this to work.

Comment: Doing this in C# didn't improve my speed at all.  But it did help me determine that Math.Cos was definitely the slow part of finding distance.  So I'm thinking I might build a new Cos function that uses a lookup array.  --  With my test data my algorithm takes 140seconds with my distance function or yours, but removing the call to Math.Cos has it takes 30 seconds, so a lookup table should be at least under 60 seconds (this being a simple modification, I will try a different algorithm in the long run)

Comment: Are you able to make the cos^2 approximation I suggested? That should cut it down to 30s. It might be worth printing out all the cos^2 values you calculate to see how different they are. The other option is to look at the Taylor expansion of cos^2(x + dx) - cos^2(x) which will tell you the error term.

Comment: I didn't fully understand it, but wouldn't precalculating it basically be reducing it to Cartesian distance?  Its been a while since I've done any geometry could you explain the Taylor expansion some more?  -- btw I precalculated a lookup array for all the values of cos^2, and the full algorithm is taking 45 seconds, approximately 15s in the algorithm itself and 30s in distance calculation

Comment: I'm suggesting taking an approximation for the cos^2 term if the longitudes are all relatively close together (meaning (Lat2+Lat1)/2 will never change much). It might be worth printing exactDistance, approxDistance and ((exactDistance - approxDistance)/exactDistance)*100 for each distance you calculate which will tell you how 'bad' the cos^2 approximation is. It is also worth noting that the Earth is not a perfect sphere so this is all approximate anyway. I think the Taylor expansion is probably overkill but it is a way to express any function as a polynomial (see Wikipedia)...

Comment: ...I can add some code in the answer to explain what I mean if you want.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered looking at [K-Cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) algorithms?

These kind of algorithms are used to "group" close/related objects (in your case, points) into clusters, based on their nearest Mean. These algorithms are usually quite optimized, and are built to handle large amount of data. In the case of 4000 points -> 1000 points, you would run a 1000-Cluster run on your data, and get back 1000 groups of points, each can be merged to a single point.

Comment: I found this [tutorial](http://www.codeding.com/?article=14) which is an easily modifiable K-Means implementation, this is far far faster than my original algorithm, but I have not compared the results yet.

Answer (score 3):

As for an efficient way, have you considered laying down a grid over the map and then assigning each point to its corresponding cell in the grid? This should have good performance.

A better (yet slower) approach would be to have dynamic cells instead of fixed cells like the suggestion above. You start with no cells at all. Then drop the first point in the map and define a cell with some predetermined dimensions around it. Then drop the next point on the map. If it falls inside the previous cell you add it to it, and possibly recenter the cell around the two points. If the point falls outside the cell then you create a second cell for it. Now you add the third point to the map and check it against the two cells. This process continues until you have added all the points to the map. I hope you get the idea. I think you could approximately limit the number of reduced points by changing the size of the cells.

EDIT (based on comment from rrenaud): You can start using a big cell size and apply one of the algorithms above. If the number of cells you end up with is too low, then you can repeat the algorithm on each of the cells and subdivide them even more. While this won't allow you to exactly reduce to a fixed number of points, you can get pretty close.

Comment: this would indeeb be a good algorithm but I don't think it fits the 4000->1000 and get centerpoint condition does it?

Comment: I think you can put a limit to the number of reduced points you want by changing the cell size. What my algorithm doesn't do is adaptively change the cell size, so that you get smaller cells when the points are all near each other and bigger cells when they are spread apart. I'm thinking about that, but haven't come up with a solution yet.

Comment: Recursively subdivide the cells until they only contain some small number of points.