# Automatically Cluster Addresses

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary, cluster-computing, routes

I work for a charity foundation that delivers 500 Thanksgiving dinners to families throughout Chicago.

I need to give 100 drivers 5 families to deliver to for next year.  My dream would to have something that automatically groups addresses into 5s that are closest to each other.  Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thank you,
Shane

Pics
https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.383650448381849.91573.143955182351378&type=1&l=f0e10e779c

Comment: it's a very non-trivial problem to do such things. you might be better off simply getting a $5 street map, plotting the addresses, and then using a marker to group them off.

Comment: It is more than non trivial because you also need to take into account the direction of the traffic, rivers bridges, etc. Two addresses may be close on a straight line, but on opposite sides of a river with the nearest bridge far away. Search for "Traveling salesman problem" or TSP, for example: http://gebweb.net/optimap/

Comment: Marcelo the site you recommended is great thank you!  Asking them if the address limit can be increased to 500+.

Comment: This site is great thank you http://gebweb.net/optimap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this site works well as it automatically orders and routes up to 100 addresses.  Trying to figure out how to do 500 but for now will work.

http://gebweb.net/optimap/

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of a question I asked, and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645574/356218) mentions [K-clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) which sounds like it would apply here

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would to group them along a space filling curve. A space filling curve reduce the dimension and reorder the points. It also subdivide the plane and when it do so it also keeps some spatial information. It's widely uses in mapping application. Especially a hilbert curve can be of big help. I've wrote a php class that can solve your problem. Write me an e-mail when you want more information. Basically you can also use a spatial extension from mysql and sort the query.